# npm does not work with sudo

Tags: node.js, npm, sudo

I am trying to install csslint with npm:

```
npm install -g csslint
```

and I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "csslint"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.1
npm ERR! path ../csslint/cli.js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, symlink '../csslint/cli.js'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, symlink '../csslint/cli.js'] errno: -13, code: 'EACCES', path: '../csslint/cli.js' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

and when I try with `sudo` Nothing happens and I do not get any message. (also when I just type `sudo npm` I see nothing happens.)

Comment: did you try changing the owner of the folder where you want to install ? `sudo chown -R $(whoami) "$HOME/.npm"` ( In your case it should be `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/bin/npm` ). (and then `npm -g csslint`).

Comment: Yes. and I also get the same error.

Comment: I reinstalled my nodejs with: `sudo apt-get purge nodejs`, cleared my apt cache with `autoclean`  and then `sudo apt-get install nodejs` and it fixed the problem.